# Внешняя команда на сервере

Tags: php

Выполняю

```
exec('tcpdump host port {тут идет записть в файл}');
```

Скрипт выполняется, как его можно остановить? 
Потому что запись в файл идет не останавливаясь. 
Нужно что бы он поработал минут 5 и остановился

Comment: `tcpdump -G {sec} -W 1 -w {filename}`